# after use the command "Docker container run" my container is not displayed

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm currently trying to learn Docker on the "Projects in Docker - 
Eduonix Learning Solutions" video tutorial, when I build my app container the console returns me the ID of the app. So far everything it's okay. Then when I run immediatly container ls it displays the container. But after some second the container is not longer displayed in the list of containers.

when I run `sudo docker ps -a` the container doesn't display neither.

I can't figure out why.

Here my Dockfile:

```
FROM node
RUN apt-get update -q && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && apt-get clean && apt-get autoclean
EXPOSE 3000
ENV APP_PATH /usr/share/app
RUN mkdir -p $APP_PATH && chown node:node $APP_PATH
WORKDIR $APP_PATH
USER node
COPY . $APP_PATH/
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

if someone has any hint, would be great,
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you check the logs. It is possible to be an error in your JS app and it crashes at a short time after npm start is executed. So the container is made, it start, but it closes soon after. That's because `docker container ls` is showing you only the running containers and you have to use `docker container ls --all` to see the non-running ones. You can use [docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) to see check the logs or you can adapt the Dockerfile so that it will keep logs of your app, by changing the last line to:
    `RUN npm start | tee /logs/app.log`
and then check that file

Comment: thanks Bogdan, for readers info I have remove the --rm flag to make the container available on the list with the --all flag if any